# ResultSet- What kind of object is it?

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist, resultset, memory-address

I'm iterating over a ResultSet and save it to a ArrayList.

```
weatherData = Arrays.asList (
                    new WeatherInfo(rs.getDate(1), rs.getInt(2)...
```

When I do a System.out.println(weatherData); I see this in the Eclipse Console:

[com.example.project.view.ChartsData$WeatherInfo@66ee6cea, com.example.project.view.ChartsData$WeatherInfo@757d0531.....

What does it mean? Is it a value I can handle in Java or not?
Is this the actual date and int that I can use in Java?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` method in WeatherInfo class. What you see is its default implementation that presents its memory location.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical model object in Java with a `toString()` method. I used Intellij Idea (recommended!) which has the ability to auto-generate `toString()` and other methods such as `equals()` and `hashCode()`. We find that having these methods on all model objects is very useful for debugging and testing.

Running `main()` will output:
`weatherInfo = WeatherInfo{country='CA', probablyOfPrecipitation=20}`

```
public class WeatherInfo {

    public static void  main(String [] args) {
        WeatherInfo weatherInfo = new WeatherInfo();
        weatherInfo.setCountry("CA");
        weatherInfo.setProbablyOfPrecipitation(20);
        System.out.println("weatherInfo = " + weatherInfo);
    }

    String country;
    int probablyOfPrecipitation;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getProbablyOfPrecipitation() {
        return probablyOfPrecipitation;
    }

    public void setProbablyOfPrecipitation(int probablyOfPrecipitation) {
        this.probablyOfPrecipitation = probablyOfPrecipitation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WeatherInfo{" +
                "country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", probablyOfPrecipitation=" + probablyOfPrecipitation +
                '}';
    }
}
```

*Top Tip*!
We use a library called `EqualsVerifier` to guarantee that all `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations are correct.

Comment: Thank you too, @Matt Friedman. I used the "Generate toString()" method in Eclipse ( Source tab-> Generate toString(). This worked for me.